# 'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift3

I have working open webLink url code in `Swift3` but when I use it gives me this warning;

> 'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Please use openURL:options:completionHandler: instead

How can I resolve it, my code under below.

```
let myUrl = "http://www.google.com"
 if !myUrl.isEmpty {
                                UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "\(myUrl)")!)
                            }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use like

```
 //inside scope use this
 let myUrl = "http://www.google.com"
    if let url = URL(string: "\(myUrl)"), !url.absoluteString.isEmpty {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }

    // or outside scope use this
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(myUrl)"), !url.absoluteString.isEmpty else {
       return
    }
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

For more reference see this sample [link](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/openurl-deprecated-in-ios10/).

Answer (score 53):

Try to use this:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "\(myUrl)")!)
```

Comment: Do you read the question?

Comment: This is a correct, concise answer. The accepted answer just has a bunch of irrelevant example code added.

Comment: Much simpler and cleaner 

Comment: @ArielAntonioFundora Did you read the answer?

Comment: @ArielAntonioFundora and to anyone else who missed the important detail. Sergey did suggest to use `open` instead of `openURL`. It's easy to miss, but is the correct answer. It eludes me why no one-click-fix is offered in Xcode.